# save the name of user who make changes in any field in table angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-cli

How can i save the name of user who make changes in any field in table using angular 4

This is my Html part:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let job of jobs" >

        <td>
            {{job.name}}
        </td>

        <td>
            {{job.date | date}}
        </td>

        <td>
            {{job.addedBy}}  <!-- The name of user who add something here -->
        </td>

        <td>
            {{job.editDate | date}}
        </td>

        <td>
            {{job.editedBy}}

        </td>

    </tr>

</tbody>
```

I want to save the name of user who is making the change and save it in job.addedBy ? any help ?

Comment: Hi .. to achive it you need a auth system (OAUTH) and a back end

Comment: i have authService and i can know the current user name , how can i save it  when he make an edit ?